# In TeX or LaTeX how do you get the precedence operator?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols, tex-history

I know how to get the following symbol:

> ## **≺**

How to I get the reverse of the precedence operator (Unicode character `U+227A`)?

That is, what is the LaTeX code for the precedence operator, especially the symbol where the left end is wide and the right-end is small or tapered to a fine point?

Comment: The command for that symbol is `\succ`.  You could find it for yourself by using [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).  But this should really be considered a duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Comment: @barbarabeeton That would work, but it is more efficient to have a short answer for a short question. If someone asks you what is the escape sequence for Unicode Character 'HOT BEVERAGE' (U+2615) ☕, then it is more time efficient to answer `\u2615` instead of giving the asker an entire table of all **149,186** Unicode characters.

Comment: I did provide the command (I always do so, if I know it, as a courtesy).  But the guidelines of this forum encourage "global" answers that are useful for many people, not just one.  Also, and off-topic, `\u2615` is not, nor is likely ever to be, a legitimate (La)TeX command; it contains digits as well as letters, which violates the definition of a TeX control sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer is due to [Barbara Beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton)

```latex
\succ
```

The successor operator looks like this after rendering:

> ## ≻